# NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key Variable not found in checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, restore, reinforcement-learning

When I restore a saved model using:

```
checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(config.pre_model_dir)
if checkpoint and checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path:
 saver.restore(session, checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path)
```

, I am getting this error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./saved_model/10_zones/10/network--1685000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

NotFoundError: Key Variable not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_21 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_18_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-0cbd09927b40> in <module>()
     42 checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(config.pre_model_dir)
     43 if checkpoint and checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path:
---> 44     saver.restore(session, checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path)
     45     print("loaded the model")
     46 else:

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in restore(self, sess, save_path)
   1800     else:
   1801       sess.run(self.saver_def.restore_op_name,
-> 1802                {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
   1803 
   1804   @staticmethod

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

NotFoundError: Key Variable not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_21 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_18_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 127, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 422, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1432, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 117, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2903, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-97-0cbd09927b40>", line 26, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1338, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1347, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1384, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 835, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 472, in _AddRestoreOps
    restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 886, in bulk_restore
    return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1463, in restore_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key Variable not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_21 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_18_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

I searched about this error, and there was a tf bug which requires to call the model using a full relative path, and I followed that path and tried values: `'./saved_model/10_zones/10'` and `os.path.abspath(config.pre_model_dir+'./../saved_model/10_zones/10')`
for `config.pre_model_dir`. Both resulted in a same error.

I also checked the name of the saved variables using 
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.framework import checkpoint_utils

```
var_list = checkpoint_utils.list_variables(config.pre_model_dir)
for v in var_list:
    print(v)
```

which is:

```
('actor/main_net/layer1/biases/Variable', [90])
('actor/main_net/layer1/biases/Variable/Adam', [90])
('actor/main_net/layer1/biases/Variable/Adam_1', [90])
('actor/main_net/layer1/weights/Variable', [30, 90])
('actor/main_net/layer1/weights/Variable/Adam', [30, 90])
('actor/main_net/layer1/weights/Variable/Adam_1', [30, 90])
('actor/main_net/layer2/biases/Variable', [60])
('actor/main_net/layer2/biases/Variable/Adam', [60])
('actor/main_net/layer2/biases/Variable/Adam_1', [60])
('actor/main_net/layer2/weights/Variable', [90, 60])
('actor/main_net/layer2/weights/Variable/Adam', [90, 60])
('actor/main_net/layer2/weights/Variable/Adam_1', [90, 60])
('actor/main_net/layer3/biases/Variable', [30])
('actor/main_net/layer3/biases/Variable/Adam', [30])
('actor/main_net/layer3/biases/Variable/Adam_1', [30])
('actor/main_net/layer3/weights/Variable', [60, 30])
('actor/main_net/layer3/weights/Variable/Adam', [60, 30])
('actor/main_net/layer3/weights/Variable/Adam_1', [60, 30])
('actor/main_net/layer4/biases/Variable', [10])
('actor/main_net/layer4/biases/Variable/Adam', [10])
('actor/main_net/layer4/biases/Variable/Adam_1', [10])
('actor/main_net/layer4/weights/Variable', [30, 10])
('actor/main_net/layer4/weights/Variable/Adam', [30, 10])
('actor/main_net/layer4/weights/Variable/Adam_1', [30, 10])
('actor/target_net/layer1/biases/Variable', [90])
('actor/target_net/layer1/weights/Variable', [30, 90])
('actor/target_net/layer2/biases/Variable', [60])
('actor/target_net/layer2/weights/Variable', [90, 60])
('actor/target_net/layer3/biases/Variable', [30])
('actor/target_net/layer3/weights/Variable', [60, 30])
('actor/target_net/layer4/biases/Variable', [10])
('actor/target_net/layer4/weights/Variable', [30, 10])
('beta1_power', [])
('beta1_power_1', [])
('beta2_power', [])
('beta2_power_1', [])
('critic/main_net/l1/biases', [90])
('critic/main_net/l1/biases/Adam', [90])
('critic/main_net/l1/biases/Adam_1', [90])
('critic/main_net/l1/weights', [40, 90])
('critic/main_net/l1/weights/Adam', [40, 90])
('critic/main_net/l1/weights/Adam_1', [40, 90])
('critic/main_net/l2/biases', [60])
('critic/main_net/l2/biases/Adam', [60])
('critic/main_net/l2/biases/Adam_1', [60])
('critic/main_net/l2/weights', [90, 60])
('critic/main_net/l2/weights/Adam', [90, 60])
('critic/main_net/l2/weights/Adam_1', [90, 60])
('critic/main_net/l3/biases', [30])
('critic/main_net/l3/biases/Adam', [30])
('critic/main_net/l3/biases/Adam_1', [30])
('critic/main_net/l3/weights', [60, 30])
('critic/main_net/l3/weights/Adam', [60, 30])
('critic/main_net/l3/weights/Adam_1', [60, 30])
('critic/main_net/l4/bias', [1])
('critic/main_net/l4/bias/Adam', [1])
('critic/main_net/l4/bias/Adam_1', [1])
('critic/main_net/l4/kernel', [30, 1])
('critic/main_net/l4/kernel/Adam', [30, 1])
('critic/main_net/l4/kernel/Adam_1', [30, 1])
('critic/target_net/l1/biases', [90])
('critic/target_net/l1/weights', [40, 90])
('critic/target_net/l2/biases', [60])
('critic/target_net/l2/weights', [90, 60])
('critic/target_net/l3/biases', [30])
('critic/target_net/l3/weights', [60, 30])
('critic/target_net/l4/bias', [1])
('critic/target_net/l4/kernel', [30, 1])
```

with what `tf.global_variables()` in my current model results in, and they are both similar:

```
<tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer1/weights/Variable:0' shape=(30, 90) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer1/biases/Variable:0' shape=(90,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer2/weights/Variable:0' shape=(90, 60) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer2/biases/Variable:0' shape=(60,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer3/weights/Variable:0' shape=(60, 30) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer3/biases/Variable:0' shape=(30,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer4/weights/Variable:0' shape=(30, 10) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer4/biases/Variable:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/target_net/layer1/weights/Variable:0' shape=(30, 90) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/target_net/layer1/biases/Variable:0' shape=(90,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/target_net/layer2/weights/Variable:0' shape=(90, 60) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/target_net/layer2/biases/Variable:0' shape=(60,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/target_net/layer3/weights/Variable:0' shape=(60, 30) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/target_net/layer3/biases/Variable:0' shape=(30,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/target_net/layer4/weights/Variable:0' shape=(30, 10) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/target_net/layer4/biases/Variable:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer1/weights/Variable/Adam:0' shape=(30, 90) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer1/weights/Variable/Adam_1:0' shape=(30, 90) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer1/biases/Variable/Adam:0' shape=(90,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer1/biases/Variable/Adam_1:0' shape=(90,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer2/weights/Variable/Adam:0' shape=(90, 60) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer2/weights/Variable/Adam_1:0' shape=(90, 60) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer2/biases/Variable/Adam:0' shape=(60,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer2/biases/Variable/Adam_1:0' shape=(60,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer3/weights/Variable/Adam:0' shape=(60, 30) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer3/weights/Variable/Adam_1:0' shape=(60, 30) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer3/biases/Variable/Adam:0' shape=(30,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer3/biases/Variable/Adam_1:0' shape=(30,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer4/weights/Variable/Adam:0' shape=(30, 10) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer4/weights/Variable/Adam_1:0' shape=(30, 10) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer4/biases/Variable/Adam:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'actor/main_net/layer4/biases/Variable/Adam_1:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l1/weights:0' shape=(40, 90) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l1/biases:0' shape=(90,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l2/weights:0' shape=(90, 60) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l2/biases:0' shape=(60,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l3/weights:0' shape=(60, 30) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l3/biases:0' shape=(30,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l4/kernel:0' shape=(30, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l4/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/target_net/l1/weights:0' shape=(40, 90) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/target_net/l1/biases:0' shape=(90,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/target_net/l2/weights:0' shape=(90, 60) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/target_net/l2/biases:0' shape=(60,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/target_net/l3/weights:0' shape=(60, 30) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/target_net/l3/biases:0' shape=(30,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/target_net/l4/kernel:0' shape=(30, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/target_net/l4/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'beta1_power_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'beta2_power_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l1/weights/Adam:0' shape=(40, 90) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l1/weights/Adam_1:0' shape=(40, 90) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l1/biases/Adam:0' shape=(90,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l1/biases/Adam_1:0' shape=(90,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l2/weights/Adam:0' shape=(90, 60) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l2/weights/Adam_1:0' shape=(90, 60) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l2/biases/Adam:0' shape=(60,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l2/biases/Adam_1:0' shape=(60,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l3/weights/Adam:0' shape=(60, 30) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l3/weights/Adam_1:0' shape=(60, 30) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l3/biases/Adam:0' shape=(30,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l3/biases/Adam_1:0' shape=(30,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l4/kernel/Adam:0' shape=(30, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l4/kernel/Adam_1:0' shape=(30, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l4/bias/Adam:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'critic/main_net/l4/bias/Adam_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

The only difference in these two lists, is `<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>`, which I do not know what is this for and how it is generated. But, I do not think if it is the problem, since any of my models that can be restored also has it.

I appreciate any help and comment to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by excluding that single variable using:

```
variables = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
variables_to_restore = [v for v in variables if 'global_step_counter' not in v.name.split('/')[0]] 

saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? I'm getting a lot of different errors while importing slime.

Comment: @Swapnil I am not aware of any other approach.